# How to disable special characters in insert mode?

Tags: gvim, key-bindings

GVim supports special characters (`ñ÷åòôùõéïéðÛáóäæç` ... etc), by holding `Alt` in insert mode.

While I'm sure this is handy for languages that use these characters, I've bound some `Alt+Keys` in insert mode, so whenever I use these special keys, its always by accident.

Is there a way to disable this feature entirely? *(besides re-binding every `Alt-Key`?)*

---

In case it's important, using GVim on X11, compiled with GTK3.

Comment: I don't think this is a Vim feature, but a feature of your OS or terminal emulator. Could you verify this by trying it in another program?

Comment: This seems to be gvim spesific, updated question.

Comment: Do you get the same behaviour with other GTK programs? I think GTK does special fu with its input methods.

Comment: No, gedit & firefox for example (both GTK3 also), don't do this.

Comment: That cannot be changed, since that is how basic keyboard handling in the terminal happens. It is not Vims fault, but how Vim receives its input.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can't do any thing. For instance, `<m-i>` is bound and always has been bound to `é`. Which is a source of a recurrent question with vim-latex. The best you could do is to ask on vim mailings list IMO. But don't expect much. IIRC, this is hard wired.